# How to change the panel visibility with richtextbox input

Tags: c#

For some reason, this one will not work:

`if (richTextBox2.Text == "settings")
                panel5.Visible = true;`

The other inputs work like "close", inputting close will close the form.

What i want to happen is when "settings" is typed into the text box, i want the panel to become visible.

Comment: Could you add some more information, like where this code is being used? The answer can vary quite a bit depending on how this is being invoked!

Comment: "other inputs work"...so are those inputs being checked in the same method?  Show us more complete code, please.

Answer (score -1):

You could try comparing in this way:

```
if (richTextBox2.Text.ToUpper() == "SETTINGS")
            panel5.Visible = true;
```

Other way to try, is debug "if" line, and check the content of Text property. Maybe, richTextBox2.Text contains some hidden characters.

I hope this could help you.